# When including bootstrap from CDN, auto completion of classes isn't working in intellisense

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I added the bootstrap CDN, I go to the code I'm trying to call bootstrap classes in the intellisense some classes(m- p- ...) are not visible, but when I call these classes they work.

My question is - when adding bootstrap files(bootstrap.css / bootstrap.min.js) to the project folder the classes are normally visible, but when I delete the bootstraps css and js files from project folder cdn do not work correctly, some classes (m-p- ..) are not visible, but when I call these classes they work. The libraries I added:

```
<!-- JQuery 3.4.1 CDN-->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap 4.3.1 CDN -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
      integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" 
        integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" 
        integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

What I don't understand, if the bootstrap cdn works correctly when the bootstrap files are added to the site folder, then why do I need cdn? what is the problem ? In the editor, in the CDN or in what and how to fix it?

Comment: Using CDN means that you scripts will be loaded only during execution time. By adding them to your project folder, the IDE reads them automatically to provide you with intelisense.

Comment: understood but not completely, thank anyway

Comment: if CDN loading when execution time, what's the point of adding bootstrap files to project folder

Comment: There is no point in adding them to the project folder. The CDN exist to ensure that the code is clean und trusted and to reduce the traffic on your server.

Comment: Danilo thank you my friend, good luck :)